# How to run a php script on fpm via cli/php?

Tags: php

I am doing a little research after finding [DeferredEventJavaWorker](https://github.com/Happyr/DeferredEventJavaWorker) and want to know if it is possible to run a php script directly on fpm via cli/php.

There are two worker implementations for java and ruby, which finally calls the fpm with some parameters and I think it should be possible with php too, right?

Here a snippet from the java worker:

```
FCGIConnection connection = FCGIConnection.open();
connection.connect(new InetSocketAddress(message.getHeader("fastcgi_host"), Integer.parseInt(message.getHeader("fastcgi_port"))));

connection.beginRequest(PathResolver.resolve(message.getHeader("dispatch_path")));
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

byte[] postData = ("DEFERRED_DATA=" + message.getData()).getBytes();
```

There is a command called `cgi-fcgi` ([source](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/directly-connect-php-fpm/)) to send stuff to fpm:

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/ping \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/ping \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Is there also a library or integrated function in php to do that?

I am aware of the shell function integrated in php, but I hope that there is another way to do this.

Comment: There is three function that you have to know:
exec — Execute an external program.
system — Execute an external program and display the output.
shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an implementation for php:

https://github.com/ebernhardson/fastcgi/

Usage is very simple:

```
$client = new \EBernhardson\FastCGI\Client('localhost', '8989');
// OR
$client = new \EBernhardson\FastCGI\Client('/var/run/php5-fpm.sock');

$environment = [
    'REQUEST_METHOD'  => 'GET',
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/full/path/to/script.php',
];
$client->request($environment, '');
```